# Calculate the days between changes in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
     id      value       Date       value_change
0   100101  AAAAAAA  01/01/2022        True
1   100101  BBBBBBB  02/01/2022        True
2   100101  BBBBBBB  03/01/2022       False 
3   100101  BBBBBBB  04/01/2022       False
4   100101  BBBBBBB  05/01/2022       False
5   100101  BBBBBBB  06/01/2022       False
6   100101  AAAAAAA  07/01/2022        True
7   100101  CCCCCCC  08/01/2022        True
8   100102  BBBBBBB  09/01/2022        True
9   100102  BBBBBBB  10/01/2022       False
10  100102  BBBBBBB  11/01/2022       False
11  100102  BBBBBBB  12/01/2022       False
12  100102  BBBBBBB  13/01/2022       False
13  100102  BBBBBBB  14/01/2022       False
14  100102  AAAAAAA  15/01/2022        True
```

I need to calculate for each id,
how many days was assigned each value,
on any given date.

For example that the id 100101 on 07/01/2022 had 2 days on AAAAAAA and 5 days on BBBBBBB.

I tried to calculate the Min(Date) but (e.g.) for AAAAAAA I calculate:
correct 1 day on 01/01/2022, incorrect 2 days on 02/01/2022, incorrect 3 days on 03/01/2022 etc.

Comment: requirement is still not clear. What is the expected output and what you have done

Comment: It sounds like you could just group by id and Date and do count aggregate. Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) :

```
df.groupby(["id", "value"])["Date"].count()
```

Or if you need to create a new column and keep the same shape of your df, use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) :

```
df["day_counts"] = df.groupby(["id", "value"])["Date"].transform("count")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

        id    value        Date  value_change  day_counts
0   100101  AAAAAAA  01/01/2022          True           3
1   100101  AAAAAAA  02/01/2022         False           3
2   100101  BBBBBBB  03/01/2022          True          11
3   100101  BBBBBBB  04/01/2022         False          11
4   100101  BBBBBBB  05/01/2022         False          11
5   100101  BBBBBBB  06/01/2022         False          11
6   100101  BBBBBBB  07/01/2022         False          11
7   100101  CCCCCCC  08/01/2022          True           1
8   100101  BBBBBBB  09/01/2022          True          11
9   100101  BBBBBBB  10/01/2022         False          11
10  100101  BBBBBBB  11/01/2022         False          11
11  100101  BBBBBBB  12/01/2022         False          11
12  100101  BBBBBBB  13/01/2022         False          11
13  100101  BBBBBBB  14/01/2022         False          11
14  100101  AAAAAAA  15/01/2022          True           3
```

Comment: Hey, that's a great idea, I will see if I can implement it in my case. I also edited a bit the question after your answer. I checked and it returns valid results for the new df as well.